# Liferay7: @Reference( target = "(component.name=String.Here)") How can I set String.Here?

Tags: liferay, osgi, portlet, liferay-7

I'm working on Liferay PortletMVC, I injected the `protected MVCActionCommand mvcActionCommand;` with the `@Reference(target = "(component.name=String.Here)",   unbind = "-")` to do some functions stuff inside the doProcessAction() method of my **MVCActionCommand** component.

My question is how can I set the `component.name in the target of @Reference` attribute, Should I put any String or should I put a defined one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**component.name** target the MVC command class name. So you need to provide the class name including it's package name.

To inject the instance variable **mvcActionCommand**, you can use something like this:

```
  @Reference(target = "(component.name=com.test.service.impl.TestServiceImp)", 
            unbind = "-")
    public void setMvcActionCommand(MVCActionCommand mvcActionCommand) {
        this.mvcActionCommand = mvcActionCommand;
    }
```

I wrote a full example here:

JAVA:

```
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
                "javax.portlet.name=YOU_COMPONENT_NAME",
                "mvc.command.name=/hello"
        },
        service = MVCActionCommand.class
)
public class LoginTestCommand extends BaseMVCActionCommand {

    protected MVCActionCommand mvcActionCommand;

    @Reference(target = "(component.name=com.liferay.login.web.internal.portlet.action.LoginMVCActionCommand)",
            unbind = "-")
    public void setMvcActionCommand(MVCActionCommand mvcActionCommand) {
        this.mvcActionCommand = mvcActionCommand;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
        System.out.println( "Login account doProcessAction" );
        mvcActionCommand.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="sayHelloURL" name="/hello">
    <portlet:param name="mvcActionCommand" value="/hello" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Check this [example](https://github.com/JoyeLuo/liferay7-sample-workspace/blob/f9da3154ad3d911cba9fc6ad149b9452b761596e/modules/User-account-hook/src/main/java/com/poc/liferay/modules/useraccount/CreateAccountActionHook.java) too on [Github](https://github.com/JoyeLuo/liferay7-sample-workspace/blob/f9da3154ad3d911cba9fc6ad149b9452b761596e/modules/User-account-hook/src/main/java/com/poc/liferay/modules/useraccount/CreateAccountActionHook.java).

See this [TUTORIAL](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017881232-Overriding-MVC-Commands-) for more details about Overriding MVC Commands.

Comment: Hi Ilyas, Thanks for the reply but after I provide the class name including it's package name I got this exception  [PortletServlet:119] javax.portlet.PortletException: javax.portlet.PortletException: processAction method not implemented. 
Here is the signature of processAction @Override
 protected void doProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

Comment: Hi @m.irouch, you need valid class component.name, check my latest modification

Comment: Great Ilyas, thanks for the help, Resolved now. 
Additional thing to what you said: The component.name shouls be a valid Liferay component like the componnent component: source : https://docs-cdn.liferay.com/ce/apps/foundation/7.0.7/javadocs/com/liferay/login/web/internal/portlet/action/package-tree.html